# What's are best Windows 7 gadgets for programmers?

Tags: productivity, windows

I am looking for a theme with gadgets that will make my life easier as a programmer.
Googling from the desktop is one feature I am looking for.
Integration with SharePoint or other bug trackers are the second.
Any other idea that might make me more productive is a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TFS gadgets:

[image: TFS gadgets]

See http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/SidebarGadgetsForTFS.aspx - it's about two years old, so ignore the Vista comments.